# Upgrade to php7 now mail() isn't working

Tags: email, debian, php-7

from phpinfo file

```
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Also installed a new Debian Stretch server.

SMTP port is open in the iptables.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue? Got any snippets of code?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I needed to install and configure exim.